# I can access https://apps.facebook.com/APP_ID/ but not /APP_NAMESPACE/

Tags: facebook

I also cannot change the namespace of my app.
When changing a setting on my app and clicking save changes, I am presented the error message

Unable to update App Namespace: An error occurred while setting the App Namespace. Please try again later.

Settings are saved (urls for instance) but namespace just can't be saved.

I also cannot create a new app (same error).

**EDIT** : It came back to life magically this morning...

Comment: It's a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/278780905548884

Comment: I saw that one. Not being able to update the app namespace is "Ok". It doesn't hurt me too much. However, if I suddenly cannot reach my app at its address, that is an entirely other problem. My app was down for 2 days, and came back to life this morning. I could only reach it through its app_id.